# Javascript break string into variables and add space

Tags: javascript, variables, split

I'm brand new to javascript and I've been at this for a while. I have

```
var formula =  '({qty} <=91999  && {qty} >= 91000  && ({oval}) && ({2inchby3inch}) && !{whitebopp}'
```

I need to break the `({qty} <=91999  && {qty} >= 91000` into a `quantity` variable, `&& ({oval})` into `shape` variable, `&& ({2inchby3inch})` into `size` variable, and `&& !{whitebopp}` into `status` variable. I'm pretty sure I should use the `split` function but I'm having trouble with it.

I need to add a space in between the `=` and `9` to go from `({qty} <=91999` to `({qty} <= 91999`, how do I do this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how `split()` could be used for this, since you don't have a consistent delimiter.

Comment: Should there be a `)` after `91000`?

Comment: seems odd. Does something generate this string? Is {qty} replaced before JavaScript gets to it?

Comment: You're basically asking how to write a parser. This is not a beginner exercise.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there probably should be a ) after 91000. I don't have to use split(), I've been trying to use it but have struggled.

Comment: The problem with using `split()` is that `&&` is the logical delimiter, but that would split `{qty} <=91999  && {qty} >= 91000` into two expressions. A regular expression like `\(.*?\)` might work better, unless you can have nested parentheses.

Comment: If this is the only format this data will be presented in, you could do this: `const [q1, q2, shape, size, status] = formula.split(/(?=&&)/); const quantity = q1 + q2`. However, if another parameter is added or removed, this will break. If you know the name of the format, someone may have already written a parser.